# I am trying to input a double from 1-100 into an array through try catch

Tags: java, arrays, range

I am trying to store user input into an array that must be a number with a range of 1-100.It is required that I use try catch for exception handling, but I have very little experience with try catch and have spent hours trying to determine where to place the statements. I have encountered an error when the program will end if the user enters a letter. I would like the program to continue until 2 valid numbers are inputted.

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
```

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter Ratings from Focus Group for Movie: ");

try{

```
  double sumFocus = 0;
  double[] arrayFocus = new double[2];

  for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
  {
      arrayFocus[i] = scan.nextDouble();
  }
  for( double num : arrayFocus) {
      sumFocus = sumFocus+num;
    }
}

catch(InputMismatchException e){



    System.out.println("Invalid input");
}
```

Comment: I recommend reading a chapter from a good Java book / online tutorial on exception handling.

Comment: I can't see anny try catch in your code.

Comment: "spent hours on trying to determine where to place the statements" - looking at 10 lines of code is not good for mental health

Answer (score 0):

Your try/catch placement is way too broad.  You must narrow it to fit within your loop, since you want the loop to continue until you have two good values.  Consider the following:

```
  double sumFocus = 0;
  double[] arrayFocus = new double[2];

  for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
      try {
        arrayFocus[i] = scan.nextDouble();
      }
      catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input: %s", scan.next());
        i--;
      }
  }

  for (double num : arrayFocus) {
      sumFocus = sumFocus+num;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This covers the most part of what I need, but I still am trying to figure out how to implement code so that negative numbers will not be considered good values.

Comment: Store the scanned value into a temporary value, then put in an IF condition to check the scanned value before storing to the array.